# setFormula to a cell using Script is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to setformula to a cell using google script and its not working. I have few conditions and double quotes and dont know how to add double quote to the sheet.

```
=if(B17<>"",IF(Form!B8 = "","",IF(Form!B8 = "Representative",index(House!A:H,MATCH(B17,House!G:G,0),8),index(House!A:H,MATCH(B17,Senate!G:G,0),8))),"")
```

How do I add this formula to a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried to simply surround it with single quotes ?

like this : *(update the Range value)*

```
sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=if(B17<>"",IF(Form!B8 = "","",IF(Form!B8 = "Representative",index(House!A:H,MATCH(B17,House!G:G,0),8),index(House!A:H,MATCH(B17,Senate!G:G,0),8))),"")')
```

Comment: Great, Worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: I used a string variable to hold the formula, but yeah this is good.  Thanks